# Unit test redux reducer using it's own initial state

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-redux

I have a reducer with a default initial state defined like this:

```
const webReducer = (state = {
    fetched: false,
    data: {}
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_DATA":
            state = {
                ...state,
                fetched: action.payload.fetched
            };

            state.data.push( action.payload.data );

            return state;
        break;
    }

    return state;
};
```

When I run a test to check for the initial state, it pass:

```
const initialState = {
    fetched: false,
    data: {}
};

it("Should have a default initial state", () => {
    expect( webReducer( undefined, {}) ).toEqual( initialState );
})
```

However, when I try to test adding data to the state, it return this error:

> TypeError: state.data.push is not a function

This is how I'm doing the test:

```
const object = {
    fetched: true,
    data: {
        config: {size: 10}
    }
};

expect(
    webReducer( undefined, {
        type: "FETCH_DATA", 
        payload: object
    })
).toEqual( object );
```

Why am i getting this error now, if before i could pass the test just fine? I also tried to pass a default state, like this:

```
expect(
    webReducer( initialState, {
        type: "FETCH_DATA", 
        payload: object
    })
).toEqual( object );
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialised data as an empty object, which doesn't have a push function on it. Try replacing it with the below, and the test should pass alright.

```
state = {
fetched: false,
data: []
```

Comment: Had to made some adjustments to test with multiple dispatchs but I got the point! Thanks =D